# PHP redirect on button click

Tags: php, redirect, post-redirect-get

I'm new to PHP programming and have a simple program where I have an index page which accepts username and password. If user doesn't exist or wrong credentials are provided then I want to show index page again with error message. Here is what I have so far on my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Bella" >

    <title>Company Name - Log In</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <div id="fullscreen_bg" class="fullscreen_bg"/>

<div class="container">

    <form class="form-signin" action="loginAction.php" method="post">
        <h1 class="form-signin-heading text-muted">Log In</h1>
        <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="">
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">
            Log In
        </button>
    <a href="register.html" class="btn btn-md btn-warning btn-block">Register</a>       
    </form>

</div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Script to Activate the Carousel -->
    <script>
    $('.carousel').carousel({
        interval: 5000 //changes the speed
    })
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

My LoginAction.php is:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

//Set the Post results to variables
$email = $_POST("email");
$password = md5($_POST("password"));

//Get the database username, passwords, etc.
include('config.php');

// Create connection with the server
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//Check for user
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE  email=" . $email . " AND password=" . $password . "";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          mysqli_close($conn);
          session_start();
          $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
          $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
          $_SESSION['admin'] = true; //user is authenticated and the user is admin
          header"portal.php"; //redirect to another page

    }
} 
else {
    mysqli_close($conn);
    echo "<div class='alert alert-warning'>No User Found</div>";
    //header("Location: http://example.com/myOtherPage.php");
    //header"portal.php"; //redirect to another page
   include"index.html";
}

?>
```

It currently shows me blank LoginAction.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I recommend you place `session_start();` at the top of all your files using sessions.

Should there be an error in DB, it will throw an headers already sent notice, since that would be considered as [outputting before header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8028957/).

You are also missing quotes around your values

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE  email=" . $email . " AND password=" . $password . "";
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Which should read as:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE  email= '" . $email . "' AND password= '" . $password . "'";
```

Having used error checking, would have thrown a syntax error.

You're also closing your connection prematurely:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
          mysqli_close($conn);
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I recommend you either remove it (MySQL will automatically close it, once the query is done), or move it after the code's execution.

Then these:

```
$email = $_POST("email");
$password = md5($_POST("password"));
```

Those should be square brackets.

```
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = md5($_POST["password"]);
```

Check for errors using:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Sidenote about MD5.

This is an old and unsafe hashing method. Read the following articles about it:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure

I recommend you use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Plus, I also recommend you use [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).

---

```
header"portal.php";
```

is missing "Location:" and brackets:

```
header("Location: portal.php");
```

as per the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

and add `exit;` after each header. Otherwise, your code will continue to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You're post variables, shouldn't they be the following:

```
$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = md5($_POST["password"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "else" should look like this:

```
[...]
else{
  mysqli_close($conn);
  echo "<div class='alert alert-warning'>No User Found</div>";
  header("Location: http://localhost/yourProject/index.html"); // here you have to put the correct url for your index.html
}
```